# Is this an example of Netty reading from a closed channel?

Tags: java, netty

I am load testing a Netty-based project by hitting it with lots of concurrent `GET` requests.

Under heavy load, I am getting many examples of this:

```
WARNING: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:247)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1147)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
[snip]
```

I understand that the error message is telling me that the last element of my pipeline is not handling this `IOException`.  I'm interested in preventing the error in the first place.

Am I correct in inferring that this means that for whatever reason Netty is trying to *read* from a closed channel?  Does that mean that my load testing tool has closed the socket to which it has written things like request headers and so on while Netty is trying to read from it, and Netty is therefore throwing this exception?

Given that I see this only under heavy load, does this mean that (for example) my event loop is too busy to actually "answer the phone" when the load testing tool "calls"?  If so, why does it try to read from the channel at all?

Comment: I've found a related thread: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/388

Comment: It is an example of reading from an abortively closed *connection.* If you do I/O on a closed channel you will get a `ClosedChannelException` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to not have this happen in practise, as it just tells you that the remote peer did non-gracefully closed connection. You should just ignore the exception if you are not interested and teardown the `Channel`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is there a reason why this logic is not, for example, in the HTTP encoding classes by default?  I understand that this might only be default behavior, but it seems like useful behavior in most cases.

Comment: imho there is not good default here and that is why we just handle every exception the same way.